# Add duplicates to each other in a Array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I currently have an Array that looks like this (Pseudo for example):

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [searchKeyword] => fendt [searchUniques] => 2266 )

[1] => Array ( [searchKeyword] => schlüter [searchUniques] => 1822 ) 

[2] => Array ( [searchKeyword] => schlüter [searchUniques] => 1725 ) 

[3] => Array ( [searchKeyword] => 1455 [searchUniques] => 1528 )
```

You can see schlüter is a duplicate in this Array. Deletion would be easy with `array_unique` but i want to add the searchUniques before deleting the duplicate.

Comment: Add `searchUniques` to what? Have you tried writing some code?

Comment: you could try looping through, and see if the searchKeyword isset(), if true, add the value of searchUniques to that other value?

Comment: @u_mulder I delete the one schlüter entry. The searchUniques from the one entry should then be added to the other one. I tried writing alot of code (probably working on this issue since 2 hours at work) but it didnt really work out.

Comment: @Shuzuka  what is expecte outcome? also put your effort here. no matter what code you have tried so for?just put your effort and expected outcome based on this input.

Comment: @Anant Expected outcome would be [1] => Array ( [searchKeyword] => schlüter [searchUniques] => 3547 )

Comment: @Shuzuka  please put your effort and expected outcome in your question. thanks

Comment: @Anant I dont exactly understand what you mean by that? Do you want me to put the comment before in the question directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.  You want to total up the 'searchKeyword' dupes as one array item.  In your example 'schluter' is a dupe keyword, so you want to total it's searchUniques as one array item for schluter.

```
<?php
$tmp = array ( 
    array ( 'searchKeyword' => 'fendt', 'searchUniques' => 2266 ),
    array ( 'searchKeyword' => 'schlüter', 'searchUniques' => 1822 ),
    array ( 'searchKeyword' => 'schlüter', 'searchUniques' => 1725 ),
    array ( 'searchKeyword' => '1455', 'searchUniques' => 1528 )
);

$newArray = array();

foreach ($tmp as $key => &$subArray) {
    if (!isset($newArray[$subArray['searchKeyword']])) {
        $newArray[$subArray['searchKeyword']] = $subArray['searchUniques'];
    } else {
        $newArray[$subArray['searchKeyword']] += $subArray['searchUniques'];
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);
// array(3) { ["fendt"]=> int(2266) ["schlüter"]=> int(3547) [1455]=> int(1528) }
?>
```

Comment: Undefined index: fendt is the error i get when i try to use your code. I tried flattening the array and some stuff but it didn't quite work out and i cant find the reason why its giving me this error message.

Comment: That's actually a php notice you're going to get because the first time thru the loop the array item is not actually set yet.  It's not an error.  I'll see if i can adjust it a bit to get rid of the notice.

Comment: I modified the code a bit to get rid of that notice by adding a condition that will first set the proper value, then increment it the next time it encounters the keyword.